# accessing portions of np.array

Tags: python, numpy

I want to have quick access to np.array elements for example from indexes from 0-6 plus 10 to the end. So far I have tried:

```
a[0:6,10:]
```

or

```
np.concatenate(a[0:6],a[10:])
```

both are giving me error, with the second one giving me:"TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index"

Edit: concatenate is still giving me problems, so I am going to post my full code here:

```
Fold_5 = len(predictorX)/5
trainX = np.concatenate(predictorX[:3*int(Fold_5)],predictorX[4*int(Fold_5)])
```

predictor X is an array with values like

```
[[0.1,0.4,0.6,0.2],[..]....]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In:

```
a[0:6,10:]
```

0:6 selects rows, 10: selects columns.  If `a` isn't 2d or large enough that will result in an error.

In

```
np.concatenate(a[0:6],a[10:])
```

the problem is the number of arguments; it takes a list of arrays.  A second one, if given is understood to be `axis`, which should be an integer (hence your error).

```
np.concatenate([a[0:6],a[10:]])
```

should work.

Another option is to index with a list

```
a[0,1,2,3,4,5,10,11,...]]
```

`np.r_` is a handy little tool for constructing such a list:

```
In [73]: np.r_[0:6, 10:15]
Out[73]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14])
```

It in effect does `np.concatenate([np.arange(0,6),np.arange(10,15)])`.

It doesn't matter whether you index first and the concatenate, or concatenate indexes first and then index.  Efficiency is about the same.  `np.delete` chooses among several methods, including these, depending on the size and type of the 'delete' region.

In the `trainX` expression adding [] to the concatenate call should work.  However, `predictorX[4*Fold_5]` could be a problem.  Are you missing a `:` (as in 10: example)?  If you want just one value, then you need to convert it to 1d, e.g. `predictorX[[4*Fold_5]]`

```
Fold_5 = len(predictorX)//5   # integer division in py3
trainX = np.concatenate([predictorX[:3*Fold_5], predictorX[4*Fold_5:]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two more short ways of getting the desired subarray:

```
np.delete(a, np.s_[6:10])
```

and

```
np.r_[a[:6], a[10:]]
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.concatenate` takes a sequence of arrays. try

```
np.concatenate([a[0:6],a[10:]])
```

or

```
np.concatenate((a[0:6],a[10:]))
```